# How to Write Unit test of a async method without completion Block in Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, xctest

I have a method which calls an API Internally. That method does not have any completion handler.

```
-(void) methodToBeTested{
    [self callAPIWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *data,NSError *error)
     {
         //Here I get the response and sets the models.
     }];
}
```

Now I need to test the method "methodToBeTested" basis of the models set after the API call.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: This honestly seems more like an integration test. For unit testing, one would typically stub this method and return mock data if it is needed to prepare for other test components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
XCTestExpectation *documentOpenExpectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"document open"];

NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]
                              URLForResource:@"TestDocument" withExtension:@"mydoc"];
UIDocument *doc = [[UIDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:URL];

[doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    XCTAssert(success);
    [documentOpenExpectation fulfill];
}];

[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:1 handler:^(NSError *error) {
    [doc closeWithCompletionHandler:nil];
}];
```

Look at the Writing Tests of Asynchronous Operations under the Testing with Xcode documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html

Comment: In the question is stated that he can't use a completion block, but with expectations in the answer you NEED a completion block